# Не получается скомпилировать код для бота discord на python

Tags: python, бот, discord

Недавно начал писать боты для дискорда, прошу строго не судить, если в коде можно что-то улучшить или если моя проблема выглядит глупо. Если что-то можно улучшить в коде - пишите, приму критику.

Когда я ввожу данный код в своем боте python для дискорда:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in coords:
        await message.channel.send("zero zero 0")
```

я получаю ошибку в консоли при компиляции:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 31, in on_message
    if msg in coords:
TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable
```

Ошибки нет, если я уберу данные строки.

На всякий, оставляю полный код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")



coords = ["корды", "база", "где база", "координаты", "координаты базы", "coords", "base", "where is base", "koordinati", "kordi", "kords", "koords", "кордс", "коордс", "базы координаты"]


@client.event


async def on_ready():
    print("УРА Я СКОМПИЛИРОВАЛАСЬ! УРА<С САТАНА ПРИШЕЛ")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def hello (ctx):
    await ctx.send (f"Hi (тут будет потом ник чела, который ввел команду)!\n\nI am bot-helper, which can you say to you all, what do you want about clan.\n\nПривет, (тут тоже)!\n\nЯ бот, который будет говорить все новости клана, которые мне извистны и которые ты пожелаешь!\n\nPrint: $help to show my commands!\nВведи $help для списка доступных команд!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)

async def coords (ctx):
    await ctx.send ("Coords: тест\nКоординаты: zero zero 0. Coords: zero zero null")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in coords:
        await message.channel.send("zero zero 0")




#connect
token = open("token.txt", 'r').readline()
client.run(token)
```

Заранее, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы переопределили список `coords` функцией:

```py
coords = ["корды", "база", "где база", "координаты", "координаты базы", "coords", "base", "where is base", "koordinati", "kordi", "kords", "koords", "кордс", "коордс", "базы координаты"]

async def coords (ctx):
    await ctx.send ("Coords: тест\nКоординаты: zero zero 0. Coords: zero zero null")
```

Переименуйте либо список, либо функцию.

***Пример:***

```py
coordinates = ["корды", "база", "где база", "координаты", "координаты базы", "coords", "base", "where is base", "koordinati", "kordi", "kords", "koords", "кордс", "коордс", "базы координаты"]

async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in coordinates:
        await message.channel.send("zero zero 0")
```

Comment: Понял свою тупую ошибку, огромное спасибо :). Впредь буду более внимателен